# How to edit external links with javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to edit all external links that inside class 
example

```
<div class='main'>
<a href='http://test1.com'>link1</a>
<a href='http://test2.com'>link1</a>
<a href='http://test3.com'>link1</a>
</div>
```

i want to edit all link that inside main class
and add before the link another link
like this

```
<div class='main'>
<a href='http://example.com/search=http://test1.com'>link1</a>
<a href='http://example.com/search=http://test2.com'>link2</a>
<a href='http://example.com/search=http://test3.com'>link3</a>
</div>
```

sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get all the links using `document.querySelectorAll('.main a')`, iterate over them and then use `replace()` on each link's href to add the missing part in href.

```js
var links = document.querySelectorAll('.main a');

for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++){
   links[i].href = links[i].href.replace("http://", "http://example.com/search=http://");

}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
<a href='http://test1.com'>link1</a>
<a href='http://test2.com'>link1</a>
<a href='http://test3.com'>link1</a>
</div>
```

Comment: or the simpler `var links = document.querySelectorAll('.main a');`

Comment: @JaromandaX yes that would be simpler, thanks for that, code updated.

Comment: Thank You :) that work but the problem it doesn't work if the url start with https , and it change the internal links too, i will try to do these changes thank you again

Answer (score 1):

if each link has it's own id like

```
<a id="link1" href='http://test1.com'>link1</a>
```

then try this

```
var currentAddress = document.getElementByID("link1").attr("href")

document.getElementByID("link1").attr("href", "http://example.com/search=" + currentAddress)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get a collection of the "a" tags using javascript (or jQuery if you have access to that) using an x-path specification.  Once you have the collection you should be able to iterate through it and set the new value.

Here's some info on x-path.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_examples.asp